# File Uploading using Retrofit2 library in Android

Tags: php, android, file-upload, retrofit2

Thanks in advance... I need help in uploading file (image file) to server using Retrofit2 library. I have already acheived simple (text based) request and response. But i am facing issue in uploading image file to server. Below is my Android Code:

**Upload Function**

```
Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
    File file = new File(mediaPath);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
    map.put("file\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"", requestBody);
    ApiConfig getResponse = AppConfig.getRetrofit().create(ApiConfig.class);
    Call<ServerResponse> call = getResponse.upload("token", map);




    call.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
            ServerResponse serverResponse = response.body();
            if (serverResponse != null) {
                if (serverResponse.getSuccess()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), serverResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Log.e("Retro", serverResponse.getMessage());
            } else {
                Log.v("Response", serverResponse.toString());
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

**Interface**

```
@Multipart
@POST("laundryapp/upload_image.php")
Call<ServerResponse> upload(
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
        @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map
);
```

**ServerResponse File**

```
public class ServerResponse {

@SerializedName("success")
boolean success;
@SerializedName("message")
String message;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public boolean getSuccess() {
    return success;
}
}
```

**My PHP Code on server**

```
    <?php

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_dir = $target_dir .basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$response = array();

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_FILES["file"])) 
{


 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) 
 {
  $success = true;
  $message = "Successfully Uploaded";
 }
 else 
 {
  $success = false;
  $message = "Error while uploading ". $target_dir;
 }
}
else 
{
 $success = false;
 $message = "Required Field Missing";
}

$response["success"] = $success;
$response["message"] = $message;
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

**My Problem**

The main problem i am facing is that i always get

> Error while Uploading

from server. I have checked the variable **$target_dir** and it contains the name of image file i am trying to upload. But in actual no file is uploading to my uploads folder... Please any help in this matter. I am exhausted too much now

Comment: https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server

Comment: this blog may be helps you to upload file on the server

Comment: Have you checked the write permission on that folder on your server

Comment: sometimes this is the thing which doesnot catch our eyes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching and helping suggestions from people, I came to know that I have not granted the permission to my file and folder. So after granting permission my code works perfectly fine. This code is correct so anybody can use this code in future... If need some help regarding this code then feel free to ask me. And thanks alot everyone who helped me to solve my problem. Have a nice day...!